# is there a way limit the arguments passed to a Ruby method in the method signature?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to create a method that accepts arguments only if the argument is either 1,2,3?

Is there any way to restrict the arguments passed to the method? Is there anything like:

`def some_method(number: [1,2,3])`

If I try to pass in `4` as the keyword argument above, it raises an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that.

You can, of course, have `if` statements inside your method to check the arguments, and then if you find a problem raise an `ArgumentError` exception:

```
raise ArgumentError, "Number must be 1, 2, or 3."
```